# How to implement https in Jenkins Windows 2012 r2

Tags: jenkins, https, openssl, keystore, keytool

I need to implement Https for the Jenkins server. for that i have done the below steps.

Step 1: openssl genrsa -out domain_name_8080.key 2048

Step 2: openssl req -new -key domain_name_8080.key -out domain_name_8080.txt

Step 3: Send this to the internal certificate authority for generating the .cer 
        file.

Step 4: I created a new keystore with the command: keytool -genkeypair -keysize 
        2048 -keyalg RSA -alias domain.name:8080 -keystore keystore2

Step 5: keytool -list -keystore keystore2

Step 6: keytool -keystore keystore2 -importcert -alias 
        domain_name_8080 -file Jenkinscert.cer(live cer file)

Step 7: keytool -list -keystore keystore2

Step 8: Copy the keystore2 to secrets folder

Step 9: edit the xml file by giving the details --httpsPort=8443 --httpsKeyStore="%BASE%\secrets\keystore2" --httpsKeyStorePassword=P*****1

I followed the above steps but unable to implement https. If anybody know how to implement https for jenkins please help. I have the files .cer, .key file with me.

Comment: Hi @Sebatian. Do you have a windows server? Is just a proof of concept in your cpu?

Comment: Hi i am using windows server. The application is uses only in intranet so their is a certificate authority internally.

Comment: Do you mean a self-signed certificate?

Comment: No certificate signed by internal certificate authority. We generate the csr and key and pass to them they will give the .cer file.

Comment: .cer files generated by  **internal certificate authority** needs special treatment like **self-signed certificate**

Answer (score 0):

## Approach  for real or production environments

The best, easy, secure, scalable and for real environments is delegate this complexity to your load balancer , proxy or something like that.

[image: https.architecture-diagram]

Advantages :

- Centralized ssl configurations in your load balancer (apache, nginx, etc)
- You just need to buy one certificate with wildcard and multi domain configuration to expose several applications with https.
- Internal applications **does not require** crazy modifications for https support. Almost all good applications must works fine regardless if is running in http or https.

Disadvantages :

- You need a new machine($$$) to host your load-balancer (optimum way). Is not recommended but you can host your load balancer in the same machine of your application.
- You need to learn load balancer configurations.Apache is something complex. I prefer nginx.

## For Jenkins

Jenkins works perfectly with nginx configurations as previous explanation. Also this approach works with your own self-signed certificates to development purposes.

- Nginx configuration

https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/033ef1cef14b734e46c0f45a344b4b6c

- Apache configuration

https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/4743990af78f8efefa0f67ce17e8e144